# C# Razor Page Dynamically Create Divs with Attributes

Tags: c#, razor

I have the following CSHTML codes:

```
<div class="container-fluid projects padding-top-small">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> 
    <div class="project-inner">
        <a href="service1.html">    
            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/image1.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="project-caption">
                <div class="project-details">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i></p>
                    <h3>Service 1</h3>
                    <p><small>Short Description 1</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> 
    <div class="project-inner">
        <a href="service2.html">    
            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/image2.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="project-caption">
                <div class="project-details">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i></p>
                    <h3>Service 2</h3>
                    <p><small>Short Description 2</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> 
    <div class="project-inner">
        <a href="service1.html">    
            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/image3.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="project-caption">
                <div class="project-details">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i></p>
                    <h3>Service 3</h3>
                    <p><small>Short Description 3</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> 
    <div class="project-inner">
        <a href="service1.html">    
            <img src="assets/img/portfolio/image4.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="project-caption">
                <div class="project-details">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i></p>
                    <h3>Service 4</h3>
                    <p><small>Short Description 4</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Pretty much everything is hard-coded HTML tags.

I want to be able to render them dynamically.

In my controller, I am retrieving a list of Service Object comprised of the following items: SERVICE_URL, SERVICE_IMAGE_URL, SERVICE_NAME and SERVICE_DESCRIPTION. These list is stored in the ViewBag (Not sure if the viewbag is the best placeholder).

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> 
    <div class="project-inner">
        <a href="SERVICE_URL">    
            <img src="SERVICE_IMAGE_URL" alt="">
            <div class="project-caption">
                <div class="project-details">
                    <p><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i></p>
                    <h3>SERVICE_NAME</h3>
                    <p><small>SERVICE_DESCRIPTION</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is to have each div rendered dynamically, so that I would be able to show up only those services available.

Controller.cs

```
public class myService
{
  public string service_url { get; set; }
  public string service_image_url { get; set; }
  public string service_name { get; set; }
  public string service_description { get; set; }
}

private void loadServices()
{
  List<myService> myServices = new List<myService>();

  for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    myService msvc = new myService();
    msvc.service_url = "service_url" + i.ToString() + ".html";
    msvc.service_image_url = "image_url" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";
    msvc.service_name = "Service " + i.ToString();
    msvc.service_description = "Service Description " + i.ToString();

    myServices.Add(msvc);
  }

  ViewBag.DataServices = myServices;
}

public ActionResult Home()
{
  loadServices();
  return this.RedirectToAction("Index", "Controller");
}
```

Rephrasing the question:
Given on my Controller that I have a list of the services and storing them to the ViewBag, how do I generate the DIVs on the Razor Page with the attributes as provided from the hard coded HTML?

Comment: Please find a tutorial on ASP.Net MVC/Razor yourself and check it out... Asking for links to guides/sites/tutorial is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Wasn't this a valid question on being able to dynamically render DIVs with certain class (and elements) through Razor pages?

Comment: Just to be clear: Are you asking how to loop on a collection of `myService` instances and output HTML for each one?

Comment: Yes, pretty much @ShaiCohen. I don't have the slightest idea how to render the HTML through the data from *myService*.

Comment: The others are quite right that this is basic MVC/Razor stuff you need to have learned first. Hint: If you have the correct @model defined in your view, your controller action just needs to `return View(myServices);`

Comment: I appreciate the honesty. I think you should start off with a tutorial on MVC. It would be difficult, if not impossible, to cover  everything you would need to know in order to do this. Although I agree with @AlexeiLevenkov that SO is not the place to ask for links to tutorials, I will suggest this tutorial. I'm fairly certain that nearly every MVC developer started here. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-1

Comment: I've scoured most of the learning tutorials from asp.net site, but I am unable to find out how to achieve what I was looking for. If this does seem easy, why hasn't anyone took a stab of providing an answer (or even a starting point for that matter?).

Comment: @Batuta, ShaiCohen give you link that covers rendering collection of items pretty well. It is very hard to get additional information without knowing what you could not find from that article. Also your current sample show no usage of model nor ViewBag, so not much to correct/improve there.

Comment: **If this does seem easy, why hasn't anyone took a stab of providing an answer (or even a starting point for that matter?)**

I understand your frustration, but simply "scouring" a tutorial will not provide you with the answers you are looking for. IMHO,  the issue you are currently facing _seems_ to be a basic lack of understanding of the underlying mechanisms of how MVC works. 

I suggest you invest the time to go through and _understand_ the  MVC tutorial I linked to. This specific question aside, it will also give you the tools to approach any new problems you are likely to have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I built a working prototype of this and will run you through the steps of each part. I then suggest you find some good basic books on MVC Razor programming and start from the beginning as there is a lot of detail to learn:

1. Use separate files for any classes and put models in the models folder.
2. Use proper standards-based naming/proper-casing of properties (leading caps for properties & classes, "CamelCase" generally)

e.g. **Models\MyService.cs:**

```
namespace WebApplication.Models
{
    public class MyService
    {
        public string ServiceUrl { get; set; }
        public string ServiceImageUrl { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
        public string ServiceDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

3. Your `Home` controller wants a `Services` action so the the URL routing is from the meaningful `/Home/Services`

**Controllers\HomeController.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication5.Models;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private List<MyService> LoadServices()
        {
            List<MyService> myServices = new List<MyService>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                MyService msvc = new MyService();
                msvc.ServiceUrl = "service_url" + i.ToString() + ".html";
                msvc.ServiceImageUrl = "image_url" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";
                msvc.ServiceName = "Service " + i.ToString();
                msvc.ServiceDescription = "Service Description " + i.ToString();

                myServices.Add(msvc);
            }

            return myServices;
        }

        public ActionResult Services()
        {
            // return a view using the ViewModel provided by LoadServices()
            return View(LoadServices());
        }
    }
}
```

4. In the view, you need to declare the type of View Model being passed
5. You need to loop over the Model (which is an enumerable collection)
6. Using Razor syntax you inject the properties of the Model's elements

**Views\Home\Services.cshtml:**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication.Models.MyService>
<div class="container-fluid projects padding-top-small">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var service in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="project-inner">
                    <a href="@service.ServiceUrl">
                        <img src="@service.ServiceImageUrl" alt="">
                        <div class="project-caption">
                            <div class="project-details">
                                <p><i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i></p>
                                <h3>@service.ServiceName</h3>
                                <p><small>@service.ServiceDescription</small></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**And the end result of all this work looks like this:**

[image]